# How to use the power provided by USB OTG?

Tags: stock-android, usb-on-the-go

I know that USB OTG supplies at least 5V of power.
I am trying to run a small LED or other types of loads through the USB OTG, but I was out of luck! How to enable the power supply through the USB OTG ?
**Note :** My phone supports USB OTG and the test LED works well even with less than 5V power.

Comment: Does your phone has an Micro USB or USB-C connector?

Comment: Yes, every phone has that.

Comment: It has micro USB.

Comment: Is that even possible ?